# Using inheritance correctly

Tags: c#, inheritance

This is hard for me to explain but I'll try my best to explain the situation.
I have two classes. `IntroductionState` and `State_episode1`. `IntroductionState` inherits from `State_episode1`. I'm creating many `State_episode1` derived classes which call `Start()` but I want each derived class to call its own custom `MyStartCoroutine()` so when the base `Start()` method is called it will instead call the derived custom method. Is there an easy way to do this or should I simply copy paste Start() method for every derived class?

The following code throws an error "No coroutine started" when I'm trying to call `StartCoroutine(MyStartCoroutine())`:

```
public class State_episode1
{
    public StateMachine_Episode1 Ep1;

    public State_episode1(StateMachine_Episode1 ep1)
    {
        Ep1 = ep1;
    }

    //start begins a coroutine which first has to set _state=2 for the state machine to continue
    public IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Ep1._state = 1;
        yield return Ep1.StartCoroutine(MyStartCoroutine());
        Ep1._state = 2;
    }
    public IEnumerator MyStartCoroutine()
    {
        Debug.Log("no coroutine started");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}

public class IntroductionState: State_episode1
{
    public IntroductionState(StateMachine_Episode1 ep1) : base(ep1)
    {
    }
    public new IEnumerator MyStartCoroutine()
    {
        return base.MyStartCoroutine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question about and what do you want to achieve? Actually, using `virtual` and `override` keywords will help

Comment: you can add `virtual` keyword in base class and in derived class you can use `override`

Comment: Even if you get the override right, the derived method just calls the base method, so I don't see a point of the derived method at all. What different behavior so you expect?

Comment: Just for your info it's an issue when I'm trying to use StartCoroutines which require a specific methodology in my state machine (that is invoking a check flag before and after the overriden Coroutine finishes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `virtual` in the base class to mark the base method as overridable:

```
public virtual IEnumerator MyStartCoroutine()
{
    Debug.Log("no coroutine started");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

and use `override` instead of `new` on the derived method to indicate an override of the base method:

```
public override IEnumerator MyStartCoroutine()
{
    return base.MyStartCoroutine();
}
```

`new` creates a "new" method that is independent of the base class methods. `override` tells the runtime to use the derived method rather than the base method.